# Php loop and writing to MySql db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with the following script.
It updates every selected field where the "state" field is ACTIVE with the values from the last pass. I only want it to update the field corresponding to the id field.

LE. I have multiple records, but only certain of them are ACTIVE.

```
ID 1 state ACTIVE
ID 2 state ACTIVE
ID 3 state DONE
```

right now the script writes in the status and speed field the same value for ID 1 and 2.
I want it to write only the corresponding values for each ID.

Hope this clears it.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, filename, status, totalsize, procent, pid, log_no FROM plow WHERE state = 'Active'");
while (($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != false) {
        $cfs = filesize($init_loc."/".$db_field['filename']);
        $procentage= ($cfs * '100')/$db_field['totalsize'];

        $out1="2";
        $pid2=$out1 + $db_field['pid'];
        $command = exec("ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -c ".$pid2, $out); 
        exec($command, $out);

        if ($out[0] == 1 && $procentage <= 99 ) {

            $fp = fopen($init_loc."/Logs/log".$db_field['log_no'], 'r');
            $cursor = -1;

            fseek($fp, $cursor, SEEK_END);
            $char = fgetc($fp);

            while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
                fseek($fp, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
                $char = fgetc($fp);
            }

            while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r") {
                $line = $char . $line;
                fseek($fp, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
                $char = fgetc($fp);
            }

            $av_speed=ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", substr($line,-6));
            mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET currentsize = '$cfs', procent = '$procentage', av_speed = '$av_speed' WHERE id = '".$db_field['id']."'") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());

            $needle1='Waiting';
            $needle2='failed';
            $needle3='no module';
            $needle4='retry after a safety wait';
            $search1=strpos($line, $needle1);
            $search2=strpos($line, $needle2);
            $search3=strpos($line, $needle3);
            $search4=strpos($line, $needle4);

                if($search1 !== false) 
                {
                    $status=ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $line);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '".$db_field['id']."'") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                elseif ($search2 !== false) 
                {
                    $status="2";
                    mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '".$db_field['id']."'") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                elseif ($search3 !== false) 
                {
                    $status="2";
                    mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '".$db_field['id']."'") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                elseif ($search4 !== false) 
                {
                    $status="Retrying ...";
                    mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '".$db_field['id']."'") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                else 
                {
                    $status="3";
                    mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '".$db_field['id']."'") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }   

            unset($search1);
            unset($search2);
            unset($search3);
            unset($search4);
            unset($av_speed);
            unset($status);
        }
        else if ($out[0] == 0 && $procentage == 100 ) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET currentsize = '$cfs', procent = '$procentage', status= '1', state = 'Done' WHERE id = '".$db_field['id']."'") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        unset($status);
        }
        else {
            $status="Unknown error";
            mysql_query("UPDATE plow SET status= '$status' WHERE id = '".$db_field['id']."'") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: `$procentage= ($cfs * '100')/$db_field['totalsize'];` multiplying with a string? seriously?

Comment: That part works, not sure what I am doing wrong there !!??

Comment: What's "wrong" there is that strings are not numbers.  PHP will usually convert stuff for you, but you shouldn't be abusing it -- particularly in that case, the `'100'` shouldn't have quotes around it, as it's never meant to be used as a string.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clearing that up. Any idea what's wrong with the rest?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Edit the question and add some more text explaining what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the value for $status. I did a simple script using your original calculations and it updates the other values as expected.

```
//Define the SQL
$query = "SELECT id, filename, totalsize FROM plow WHERE state = 'ACTIVE'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        //Do some simple calculation before updating the database
        $id = $row['id']; // Set the id
        $cfs = filesize($init_loc."/".$row['filename']); //Get file size
        $procentage= ($cfs * 100)/$row['totalsize']; // Percentage
        echo 'Filesize: ' . $cfs . '<br />' . 'Percentage: '. $procentage . '<br />';
        $update = "UPDATE plow SET procent = '$procentage' WHERE id = '$id'";
        $updateResult = mysql_query($update);
    }
} //End check for affected rows
```

So it means there must be something that makes the status remain the same for both ids. Trace the status variable to where the value originates and see if you can figure out why they're the same value.

Comment: Okay, so how would you do it?

Comment: Tell me more about what you want to do and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there a reason you are bringing the records of the ACTIVE out before updating the table?

Comment: For every ACTIVE record, I am doing those calculations (percentage, speed ...) and after that I want it to be written back to the DB.

Comment: But you want to do this for a specific ID that is also ACTIVE?

Comment: OK I think I understand what you are trying to do now. Give a sec. Let me look at the code again.

Comment: I have updated the answer. See if that works. I will try and test it as well.

Comment: Is not updating the records at all. I tried the foreach loop but didn't had to much luck with it, also ... I've been stuck here for 3 days now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same thing ... is not updating any of the ACTIVE records.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Try it one more time.

Comment: Does it give an error? What is the error. It really should work now. I cannot recreate all the variables you have in there.

Comment: Update the question hard coding all the variables needed within the while loop.

Comment: you can see it here ... I am using firebug ... no errors no nothing ... I deleted the address, don't want people accessing this for now.

Comment: Did you notice that I had tester as the db? Did you replace that with your db? I have gone ahead and done that. If you didn't do so before then try the code again. I think it should work now unless maybe the results should be the same in the first place.

Comment: I didn't notice that ... I tried a couple of other things, foreach ($db_field as $db_field['id']) thought maybe I can force it that way ... but still no luck.

Comment: I wonder why the execution time jumped from 200-300 ms to 3-5secs ??

Comment: Actually must be from something else. I see that the for each loop is also wrong. I have removed that because it does it for each column in the db. Hence the execution time jump.

Comment: Execution time dropped again to previuos values but the script "works as before" updates every field ...with same value

Comment: Are you using Ajax? Why no error? Check the calculations. I tried with different calculation and it entered the desired values so I am not sure about yours. Sorry I have not been able to help.

Comment: Ajax, yes ... I'll try to start from scratch see if I can find a more simpler way of doing this ... thanks anyway

Comment: See changed answer. I hope that helps.